# Add white-space padding to paragraph

Tags: html, css, whitespace, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to limit the number of characters in a paragraph to a specific number. If the text is less than this then I want to pad it with whitespace and if it's longer then I will truncate is with an ellipsis. I want all containers that contain paragraphs to be the same size.

I'm using a responsive grid and so my container will resize dynamically to the length of the paragraph. I've tried added pre-wrap to the p element but my divs won't resize. It seems to be still ignoring the added whitespace.

```
p
{
white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/RFBza/4/

Comment: p { text-indent: 1em; }

Comment: You want to make the size of the div similar .. irrespective of content ..??

Answer (score 0):

Omg. But in case you for some reason wish to do it exactly so, try adding a bunch of `&nbsp;` codes divided by spaces. So, where you added five spaces, now add `&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;`.
But of course that is still terrible idea.

Comment: Why the 'omg'? If you think my idea is terrible then I'd be grateful for suggestions on how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

`white-space` is not meant to "lengthen" any divs or add padding to fill in space.  It is merely meant to determine how the wording wraps in the containing div.  If you wanted that text to overflow the div, for example, you could with `white-space`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Now, if you're trying to accomplish that they all look similar, the quick, dirty way is to add a minimum height to the containing divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/RFBza/6/

The problem with this is that you're wording will constantly change, so the actual height may change (and like you said, it's responsive so as you resize this will no longer work either)

There are several other techniques to get this desired effect, but they all require either some JQuery, some markup changes, or even PHP (for if you want a string to only be so many characters, otherwise show ellipsis) etc...

You could even go as far as adding that to the `p` selector in your CSS, but be careful because that would apply to every single paragraph.  Maybe you can use a few more selectors to get specific.

```
p
{
   white-space:pre-wrap;
   min-height:192px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RFBza/7/

Also, use PHP to determine a length and show an ellipsis if it exceeds that.  In this case, 50 characters.

```
echo mb_strimwidth("Your paragraph goes here", 0, 50, '...');
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm truncating the string on the server side in ASP.NET. The minimum height approach won't work just because of how dynamic the layout is. What I'm looking for is a sort of min-chars for the p element so that regardless of the layout, the paragraph with pad to contain a certain number of characters, thus resizing the outer container uniformly.

Comment: Then you should be able to just use `min-height`.  If you know your font size, line-height, and maximum amount of characters, then you should end up with a consistent height of that container anyway.  Min-height allows the container to become taller when the browser window is condensed (but to a certain point, since it's repsonsive, they will stack and their heights will no longer be measurable to be uniform anyway.)  Otherwise, I would look into making them a little bit larger than you plan, and using `table-cell` to center them for a nice look http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/